# creating customized popuser using label and buttons (swift/ios)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create custom popopview using labels and button, something like this;
[image: custom popop]

First, created a label with opac background;

```
    let opacLabel = UILabel(frame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.screenWidth,self.screenHeight))
    opacLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.9)
    view.addSubview(opacLabel)
```

then a layer for popup view;

```
    let categoryMenuLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10,40,100,300)) 
    categoryMenuLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    categoryMenuLabel.clipsToBounds = true
    categoryMenuLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 7
```

and then a button

```
    let saveButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(spaceX,400,150,40))
    saveButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    saveButton.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetia", size: 25)
    saveButton.setTitle("Save", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    saveButton.addTarget(self, action: "categorySaveButtonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    categoryMenuLabel.addSubview(saveButton)
```

finally added categoryMenuLabel to main view and changed order;

```
    self.view.addSubview(categoryMenuLabel)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(opacLabel)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(categoryMenuLabel)
```

With this configuration, when I try to press button, instead of button, it pressed the table cell under label. 
I also couldn't manage to disable touch actions outside of the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enable user interaction on the label. It's off by default, and that prevents it's children from receiving any user interaction, as well:

```
categoryMenuLabel.userInteractionEnabled = true
```